# Regular expression to validate image source

Tags: regex, xss

I am writing a web app where I accept image source as url query parameter. I want to validate image source to make sure that user/caller is not sending a request which can result in XSS or something like that. Can you suggest me a good way of validating the image src or a regular expression which can make sure that no malicious content is getting pushed to my server and can impact end user.

I can think of following format of image sources:

1. http://foo.com/bar.jpg (absolute)
2. /foo/bar.jpg (relative)
3. foo/bar.jpg (relative)

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: At this point I am using Java.

Comment: Care to give examples of whatever you consider XSS?

Comment: The only thing which I can think of is a script tag but there can be other things which can impact.

Comment: Then see my answer: you have a ready-to-use tool in Java (and most other languages for that matter) which allows you not to have to resort to regexes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex is probably not what you want. Since you are using Java, use `URI`:

```
final URI input;

try {
    input = URI.create(inputStringHere);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Not even a valid URI: deal with it
}

// do other tests on input
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes you are taking an url as a parameter, and then retrieving the data from that url server-side.

A regex alone is not the way to go, as it only checks the filename, and doesn't tell you if the actual data is malicious. I would do this in three steps:

1. Test the filename to make sure it ends in a supported type. This isn't for security, it's to avoid downloading unusable data, and is actually optional. Something like: `/\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/`
2. Hit up the webserver that the data is located on with a  HEAD request, instead of a GET request. Ensure the returned mime-type matches the expected image type. This is the first line of security. If it isn't good, don't fetch the data. Otherwise:
3. Download the data, and test it locally to make sure it really is what mime-type the server said it was. If you are in a unixy environment, try piping the file data through `file -I -`.

Even this won't absolutely *guarantee* safety, but it should weed out the most obvious vectors for attack.